# Underline a Label in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, hyperlink, label, underline

Hey I have tried to underline a Label in C#. What I am trying to do is modifying the Label control so it looks like a hyperlink.

I have tried a lot of stuff and looked at many sites/blogs but haven't found a solution. I thought about using a TextBlock instead but there must be a way to do it with Label controls.

```
<Label Name="link" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Blue"></Label>
```

I hope you can help me and appreciate any kind of help.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I am using the WPF framework.

Comment: Do you have to use a `label`?  Can you use a `TextBlock` instead?

Comment: I don't know. I guess I can use a TextBlock but is it not possible somehow to accomplish this with a Label?

Comment: Have a look at TextBlock. You can put a TextBlock inside a label. See TextBlock.TextDecorations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use a Label with underline. Use a TextBlock instead. The difference is not very noticeable besides the better styling options for a TextBlock.

Comment: I think I am just going with this answer. This will make it a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Linked Label:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel(v=vs.110).aspx

Or:

```
this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

Disregard after your edit stating it's a WPF project.

Comment: I am sorry for forgetting to mention that I am using WPF.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a link, you can use a [`HyperLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the content for a label.

```
<Label x:Name="link">
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
        Click here to go to StackOverflow
     </Hyperlink>
</Label>
```

It will underline the text and set the font color to a blue color. I don't know how to actually make it navigate to that page, however. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I am still new at WPF and C# but it appears that a label contains a built-in text block. I have a project with a lot of buttons on the main menu. Each button has a label next to it. The requirement was to change the color of the label and underline it when the button next to it has focus.

There is probably a way easier way to do this but this is how I accomplished it:

1. I wrapped each label-button pair into a stack panel so that there was only one child other than the button (which is the label).
2. Then I can use `UIHelper` and `VisualTreeHelper` to find the built in text block to add and remove the underline.

Hope this helps someone.

**The XAML:**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            >
  <atris:AtrLabel Width="15"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Content="1"
                  Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"
                  />
  <atris:AtrButton Margin="0,0,0,0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                   Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
                   Content="Deposit"
                   >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=SetLabelForeground}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=RemoveLabelForeground}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </atris:AtrButton>
</StackPanel>
```

**The ViewModel:**

```
protected sealed override void InitCommands()
  {
     SetLabelForeground = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(SetForegroundOnLable);
     RemoveLabelForeground = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(UnSetForegroundOnLable);
  }
   //changes the number back to gray and removes underline 
  private void UnSetForegroundOnLable(RoutedEventArgs obj)
  {
    Label closestLable = GetChildLabel(obj);
    closestLable.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#666666"));
    TextBlock childTextBlock = UIHelper.FindVisualChild<TextBlock>(closestLable);
    childTextBlock.TextDecorations.Remove(TextDecorations.Underline[0]);
  }
  //changes the number to blue and underlines it
  private void SetForegroundOnLable(RoutedEventArgs obj)
  {
    Label closestLable = GetChildLabel(obj);
    closestLable.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF009df3"));
    TextBlock childTextBlock = UIHelper.FindVisualChild<TextBlock>(closestLable);
    childTextBlock.TextDecorations.Add(System.Windows.TextDecorations.Underline);
  }
  //gets the number next to the button
  private static Label GetChildLabel(RoutedEventArgs obj)
  {
    Button buttonThatHasFocus = (Button)obj.OriginalSource;
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(buttonThatHasFocus);
    Label closestLable = UIHelper.FindVisualChild<Label>(parent);
    return closestLable;
  }
```